# using webpack to compile redux example todos,but exists error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

This will exist error:ERROR in ./src/reducers/todos.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (15:13)

case 'TOGGLE_TODO':

```
  return state.map(todo =>
    (todo.id === action.id)
      ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}
         ^(error here)
      : todo
  )
```

case 'TOGGLE_TODO':

```
  return state.map(todo =>
    (todo.id === action.id)
      ? Object.assign({}, todo, {completed: !todo.completed})
      : todo
  )
```

but change the code like the last will success,I want to know why the first code can not be compiled successful.Appreciate any help!

Comment: i haved add codes and point the error position,appreciate any help,thanks!

Comment: Thank you all,I really appreciate your help,thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you have babel set up to support the Object Spread Operator.
Look at this page of the Redux docs for reference:
https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator

Comment: Thank you very much,I have solve the problem.

Comment: For others:if you have the same problem,run npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread,and create a .babelrc add {
    "presets": [ "env"],
    "plugins": [ "transform-object-rest-spread"]
}